# R: How to stop update.formula from wrapping RHS in extra brackets

Tags: r, formula

I'm writing a function that, among other things, calls `pgmm` from the `PLM` package based on an updated formula.  However when I use `update.formula` from `stats` the right-hand side (RHS) of the formula becomes inexplicably wrapped in parentheses.  I wouldn't care except that the `formula=` argument in `pgmm` does not accept this syntax.

My baseline formula:

```
 model.AR1.1X = y ~ lag(y,1) + lag(x,1)
```

I use this for some preliminary estimations and then update via:

```
gmm.form = update.formula(model.AR1.1X, . ~ . | lag(y, 2:6) 
# calling this formula shows:
gmm.form
y ~ (lag(yi, 1) + lag(x, 1) | lag(y, 2:6))
```

Notice the bracket after the tilde `~`, **(** lag(y ... etc.. and the double-bracket at the end 2:6)**)**

When I then call `pgmm` I get the error:

```
 Error in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute
```

There is no problem when I write out the formula myself (without extra brackets), but this would complicate my code.

**Is there a way to prevent this behaviour in** `update.formula`**?**  Alternatively, is there a `gsub` equivalent that can be used on a formula object to remove these brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either modify the call or use paste as in the comments. Here's the modify method.

```
gmm.form[[3]] <- gmm.form[[3]][[2]]
#y ~ lag(y, 1) + lag(x, 1) | lag(y, 2:6)
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize formula objects behave (kind of?) like lists.  Odd that `update.formula` adds this wrapper, but easily solved.  Many thanks!